# Rear audio ports always show as "Not plugged in"

Tags: audio, windows-10, drivers

I've been having this issue with Windows for about a week now which NONE of the back panel/front panel connectors (speakers, microphone) are being recognized by Realtek audio manager. The only audio input/outputs that are showing are the optical.

Troubling shooting steps I've tried (none worked):

- COMPLETELY uninstall all Realtek drivers/reinstall
- Tried using windows drivers
- Upgraded chipset driver
- sfc /scannow
- Reinstall Windows 10

I called EVGA and asked for RMA but then I booted into a Ubuntu OS and all the ports work FINE. It must be a problem with Windows 10.

Can you think of any other troubling shooting step I can try to fix this annoying issue?

Screenshot of playback devices:

[image]

Screenshot of Realtek HD Audio Manager:

[image]

Edit:

After looking in Device Manager under Audio inputs and outputs, I don't see any speaker/microphone listings, only the optical crap:

[image]

Comment: Click View in Computer Management and select "Show hidden devices", and then navigate to "Audio inputs and outputs". What are the additional devices that appear?

Comment: Still no sign of any Speaker/Microphone device. Only the optical.

Comment: Have you tried disabling USB AUDIO CODEC in Sound -> Playback and then plugging in a headphone in the jack?

Comment: Yup, no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue my self. Somehow "Disable front panel jack detection" in the Realtek settings made all my other ports work again.

Edit:

I had to RMA my motherboard in order to get working audio ports. Looks like it was a hardware issue.